# Работа с датой

Tags: javascript

Доброго всем времени суток. Задача в следующем: имеется сегодняшняя дата, получаем число, добавляем 1 день, если это последнее число месяца + 1, то выводим 1, иначе выводим число без изменений, скажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

```
function inn(i, j, k) {
    if (i < k) {
        i = 1;
    }
    document.write(i);
} // проверка последнего дня дня
var i = 1;
var j = 1;
var k = 1;
var d = new Date()
i = d.getDate();
j = d.getMonth();
i++;
j++;

if (j = 1 || j = 3 || j = 5 || j = 7 || j = 8 || j = 10 || j = 12) {
    k = 31;
    inn(i, j, k);
} // проверка месяцев с 31 днем
if (j = 4 || j = 6 || j = 9 || j = 11) {
    k = 30;
    inn(i, j, k);
} // проверка месяцев с 30 днями
if (j = 2) {
    k = 28;
    inn(i, j, k);
} // проверка февраля
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Интересно. Я не знал, что есть закономерность того, что в каких-то месяцах 31 день, а в каких-то 30. 
ПО поводу ошибки. Чтобы вывести 1 вместо последнего числа в месяце, по вашему алгоритму, надо в функции `inn()` посмотреть, день равен `k` или нет. Если равен, то присвоить `i` единицу. А вы же присваиваете единицу только тогда, когда `i` не равен `k` (т.е. как я понял, последнему дню), и НЕ равен последнему дню месяца.

Comment: Оу, да, спс, только это не решает проблемы, проблема в проверке условия, вместо того, чтобы проверить например:
if(j=2){}
Он выполняет:
j=2, а потом уже выполняет проверку.

Comment: if (j == 2) 
!!!!!!! Не спешите!!!!

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все заработало!

Comment: Тогда примите ответ. Галочка снизу от знака руки с большим пальцем вниз.